# How can I contact someone without using chatty comments?

Tags: support, comments, users

How can I contact someone without using chatty comments? I see no way to do this.

Answer (score 11):

These aren't discussion forums, it's dedicated questions and answers.  For extended discussions, you can try asking a user via a comment on their content to join you in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gaming.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If both users comment a few times, they'll also be prompted automatically to move to chat. This has the benefit of creating a room, auto-moving comments into the room, and giving those users explicit access to the room, even if they didn't have the required reputation to chat.